# Как я могу использовать механизмы наследования и swagger в своем API одновременно?

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Большая часть моих методов в API реализовано по такой схеме:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomeController : ApiContriollerBase<SomeRequestModel>
{
    public override void Method1() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}


[Produces("application/json")]
public abstract class ApiContriollerBase<TRequest> : ControllerBase
    where TRequest : new()
{
    TRequest ApiRequest = new TRequest();

    ApiResponse ApiResponse = new ApiResponse();

    [HttpPost]
    public ApiResponse EntryPoint([FromBody] TRequest request)
    {
        // Do something. Method1(), Method2()...

        return ApiResponse;
    }

    // Some virtual methods
    public virtual void Method1() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public virtual object Method2() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Когда я пытаюсь использовать swagger, он не может сгенерировать swagger.json и выдает ошибку: "Fetch errorundefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json". Насколько я понимаю swagger не может понять мой механизм запросов. Мне бы не хотелось менять эту схему из-за swagger. Есть ли способ исправить ошибку?